# Why can I only use the `Web3 Provider` option to connect to `geth` when using a local instance of the Remix Solidity Compiler?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, browsers

Why can I only use the `Web3 Provider` option to connect to `geth` when using a local instance of the Remix Solidity Compiler?

When starting `geth`, I use the following command-line:

```
geth --rinkeby --datadir=.rinkeby --cache=512 --bootnodes=enode://a24ac7c5484ef4ed0c5eb2d36620ba4e4aa13b8c84684e1b4aab0cebea2ae45cb4d375b77eab56516d34bfbd3c1a833fc51296ff084b770b94fb9028c4d25ccf@52.169.42.101:30303 --rpc --rpcaddr "localhost" --rpcport 8545 --rpccorsdomain "*"
```

Trying to connect to `geth` from the online Remix Solidity Compiler on port 8545 (Web3 Provider), I get the error: "Invalid JSON RPC response: ".

However, if I use my local (downloaded) version of the Remix Solidity Compiler, then everything works flawless. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

I had experienced the same issue.

When you connect online remix to localhot geth or any public node it expects same protocol(http/https) to connect.

1. If you access remix in https you geth should be in https
2. If you access remix in http the geth should be in http.

Comment: How do I set `geth` to HTTP or HTTPS?

Comment: Refer this https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/26026/how-to-ssl-ethereum-geth-node