# How To SSL Ethereum Geth Node?

Tags: go-ethereum

I have a geth node up and running but I want to be able to connect to it via https.  For example https://eth-node-domain.com:8545 or https://121.213.231.24:8545  How can I go about doing this?  I have been google searching for the past week but cant seem to find anything about this.

I am running Ubuntu on digital ocean

I have tried to install lets encrypt cert but that did not work.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install certbot
sudo certbot certonly --standalone -d mynodesite.com
```

Comment: how did you setup the node? can you explain?
I am also trying to setup on cloud, I need guidelines

Answer (score 9):

Setup nginx as proxy server for your node below script for your reference

```
server {

listen 443 ssl;
server_name your.domain.com;

ssl_certificate /usr/local/nginx/conf/server.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /usr/local/nginx/conf/server.key;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;

location / {

    proxy_pass http://localhost:8545; # my existing apache instance
    proxy_set_header Host $host;

    # re-write redirects to http as to https, example: /home
    proxy_redirect http:// https://;
}}
```

Comment: `ssl on` directive is now deprecated. should be removed and change `listen 443 default_server` to `listen 443 ssl`

Answer (score 0):

You can use nginx as a frontend managing SSL certificates. And has it working as reverse proxy to geth.